# Bike brake bleed question

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

so after bleeding my Tektro mineral oil brakes, the brakes appear to no longer be functional. when I depress the lever until it touches the handle bars. I am still able to spin the wheel. I think it wasn't a bad bleed as I feel as if I am applying a rather substantial amount of force to the lever. I am assuming the problem is mineral oil on the brake rotor/pads. I have already tried using an oven cleaner spray and soapy water to clean the rotor and changing the brake pads(to used ones) to no avail.

So my question is as follows: should I buy a brake cleaner and a set of new pads? or should I attempt to cut my losses and get the entire brake system replaced?

Answer (score 3):

If you can pull the lever to the bars there something more wrong than rotor contamination.

I would guess air got in the system but you just did a bleed. I’d Check fluid level, try bleeding again.

You may also need to pump levers to move pads onto rotors if you pushed them back.

Comment: but it takes alot of force to move the lever to the handle bars. I can get the front wheel to lock up with minimal effort. but a similar amount of force on the rear brake does nothing but slow the bike down marginally.

Comment: I feel like its more a pad/rotor contamination thing but i dont know how to tell?

Comment: Is it both front and rear?

Comment: The problem is only the rear brake as it is the only brake i attempted to bleed.

Comment: @MohammadAli thoroughly clean the rotors caliper etc. , swap front/ rear pads, see if problem gies away, if it does rear pads contaminated and should be replaced

Comment: As stated in my question I’ve already tried cleaning the rotor with oven cleaner and soap and I’ve already tried swapping the pads with some older ones I had laying around. Should I be using a particular cleaning solution?

Comment: I use a little mineral spirit on a kitchen towel. I wonder if you have un-bedded-in the pad and rotor. Try bedding in procedure and see if it helps. I wonder if oven cleaner was too strong. I would not let it near my bike for sure.